# Print to touch bar

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

Is there a way to print things to the touchbar, preferably with the terminal? I have been trying to find documentation but I can't find any.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: I want to display a timer

Comment: Something like [this](https://touch-bar-timer.alexzirbel.com)?

Comment: Yes, but I want it to be able to sync it with a timer that I'm running in emacs

Comment: You have a lot of requirements that you didn't include in your question.  We can't help you if you don't provide the info.  See [ask] for important info about asking questions on this site.

Comment: I did not add any requirements to my question.  The question was whether there is a way to print to the touch bar, and it still is.  If I wanted to ask about how to sync a timer on the touchboard to one running in emacs, I would have asked that, but that would be relevant to very few people, and I am interested in something more general.  That would just be a problem that I could solve if I knew the answer to the question that I am asking.

Comment: There's no print to the Touch Bar function available.  However, something like [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/documentation-touch-bar.html) might be able to do what you want.  I've never used it but the docs say it can show info on the Touch Bar.

Answer (score -1):

Some AppleScript

```
-- https://forum.latenightsw.com/t/set-touchbar-to-show-f-keys/638/8
set touchBar to true
try
    set touchBarText to do shell script "pgrep TouchBarServer"
on error
    set touchBar to false
end try
if touchBar is true then
    set fkeysSet to true
    try
        set fkeysSetText to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.touchbar.agent.plist | grep YOUR.APP.PREFS.HERE | grep functionKeys"
    on error
        set fkeysSet to false
    end try
    if fkeysSet is false then display dialog "Follow the instructions, etc."
end if
```

Comment: This does not seem in any way to relate to the question? Cmd-Shift-6 saves a screenshot of what's on the TouchBar. It does not in allow you to display anything on the TouchBar.